# physical machine to virtual machine and place into VirtualBox

Tags: vmware, virtualbox

I am trying to take a newly created virtual machine and have it run on VirtualBox. I want to create a virtual machine out of my existing machine (Windows 7 Pro 64bit) so I used VMWare's free converting tool in order to create the image. I am having difficulties when I try and load the vmdk file to VirtualBox. I have read posts and many forums that say that you are able to use a vmdk image in VirtualBox but after many attempts I have not been able to do it. I have tried booting off the backup disk and did not work. Anyone tips on how to put a virtual copy of your physical machine (Windows 7 Pro 64bit) and get it to boot and run in VirtualBox? Any tips would help. The thing is that all my other VM's work with no problem except the virtual copy of my physical machine.

Comment: Any details what actually goes wrong? Error messages etc.

Comment: We'd need to know what specific error messages you're getting. Otherwise we're only going to point you back to the general guides that it sounds like you've already read, which won't help you.

Comment: I am not able to get it to boot. I read in a few forums that you can add a vmdk file through the Vbox manager but in VirtualBox version 4.1.2, there is not an option to add VMs only modify. I am able to boot it in Workstation 8 but want to run it in VBox because I like it better and think it handles 64bit better. Why is it that I do not have the option, even when creating a new, to select the vmdk file in virtualbox? Does this version have bugs?

Comment: Error: Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.

Comment: Can you boot in safe mode? Try clicking `F8` (maybe a few times in a row), or if it doesn't work try to send `Reset` (`Host+R`, or from VirtualBox dropdown menu) while Windows is attempting to start, and then a screen prompting you whether to start normally or in safe-mode should appear.

Comment: I am not able to boot at all.

Comment: I am beginning to think that there may be something wrong with my installation of VirtualBox becsause all of the features that have seen listed from other forums are not there. I am getting really frustrated because I am able to work with it in Workstation 8 but not VirtualBox. I am beginning to think that Workstation is a better product.

Comment: in this article http://www.sysprobs.com/physical-virtual-virtualbox-virtualbox-p2v , in step 4 it says "Now add the newly created vmdk file to VirtualBox media manager as shown below", I do not have to option to add. Only modify and create. It works fine in Workstation 8. It seems so simple but it will not work for me. I downloaded VirtualBox 4.1.2 for Windows.

Comment: I confirm - I have VirtualBox 4.1.0 and have the same situation like you - there are no `New` and `Add` options, only `Copy` and `Modify`. Weird change by Oracle. Maybe try creating new virtual machine from scratch, and in the phase of choosing hard disk check `Use existing hard disk` - then you are able to import (not from the drop-down, but click the button on the right).

Comment: Windows tends to hiccup when you try to boot it from a different SATA or IDE controller than the one on which it was installed.  In addition, even if you get it to boot, you will have to reactivate unless you're still within the 30-day period before activation.  And if it's an OEM version of Windows 7, the activation will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested [Disk2VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415), from Mark Russinovich?

It's hard to think any way to convert a physical machine into a virtual one, and I think VirtualBox is able to use VHD files.

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried to use Disk2vhd. I was testing it on an old XP machine. Works great with Windows XP and Virtual PC but wasnt able to use it with virtualbox. I was getting the same messages using Disk2vhd as I did with VM converter. I think that Microsoft is the root of the issue. I think they are just mad that they are not able to operate 64 bit guest OS on a 64 bit Host. Their Virtual PC software is a joke. This is the reason for wanting to use virtualbox. I have found that VMWorkstation 8 will also handle 64 bit guest but it is not free and Windows blows up because of the activation key.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [XenConvert available from Citrix](http://www.citrix.com/english/ss/downloads/details.asp?downloadId=2306318) for converting machines to VHD without issues in the past (Disk2VHD failed for me too), although I only ever converted to VHD (for HyperV) rather than VMDK.